# how to get word placed in certain line and col of stdin?

Tags: perl

it is desirable to do this by perl, awk etc oneliner

for example i have print

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1320 | vkrylov | 2010-12-07 06:47:30 -0800 (Tue, 07 Dec 2010) | 1 line

rollback to 1306
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i need to get word in line:col 2:3, that is vkrylov

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, this look like output from `svn log`. If you can change the options used when `svn` was run you can add the `--xml` option to a more machine readable output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl:

```
 perl -ane 'print $F[2] if $.==2'
```

Columns (`$F[]`) start at 0, lines (`$.`) start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this as Subversion log output. If you wanted just to capture the user ID, you might do either of these:

```
m/.{9}([^|]*?[^|\s]*)\s+/.
```

However, I usually change the record limiter to `( '-' x 72 ) . "\n"`, like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$RS>;

local $RS = ( '-' x 72 ) . "\n";
while ( <> ) { 
    my $a = $_;
    chomp;
    next unless m/\S/;
    my ( $revision, $user, $time, undef, $comment )
        = split( /\s*\|\s*|\n\n/m, $_, 5 )
        ;
    # Some people leave trailing lines in comments, so I modify the comment.
    $comment =~ s/\n+\z/\n/m; 
    ...;
}
```

Comment: to answer your question about "t-christ", here's 2 hints: (1) Look at the website his SO profile points to; (2) You LIKELY have seen his real name before. Tell me if those 2 ring a bell or not.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, the best solutions is to use curses.

From [Perl 5 FAQs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-use-curses-with-Perl%3f)

> **How can I use curses with Perl?**
>   The Curses module from CPAN provides a
>   dynamically loadable object module
>   interface to a curses library. A small
>   demo can be found at the directory
>   http://www.cpan.org/authors/Tom_Christiansen/scripts/rep.gz
>   ; this program repeats a command and
>   updates the screen as needed,
>   rendering rep ps axu similar to top.